# Program is not producing expected result based on case statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a console app that waits for the User to enter a number between 1 and 4. Depending on the selection, a case statement will then print out the appropriate console statement, or go to a different method. When I start the program and enter the number, nothing is returned and the program ends.

if the user selects number 1 I want to print out a line of text and then execute program called NewEntry. It doesn't seem to even start that program.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //initial Prompt

        Console.WriteLine("***Welcome to the Asset Directory***");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Select an Option");
        Console.WriteLine("1. New Entry");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Edit Entry");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Look Up");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Print Master List");

        int userInput;

        userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine(userInput);

        switch (userInput)
        {
            case '1':
                Console.WriteLine("1. New Entry");
                NewEntry();
                break;
            case '2':
                Console.WriteLine("2. Edit Entry");
                break;
            case '3':
                Console.WriteLine("Look Up");
                break;
            case '4':
                Console.WriteLine("4. Print Master List");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection");
                break;

        }

    }

    static void NewEntry ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the DSCADA Asset Information");
        Test_RTU = new DSCADA_RTU();
        Test_RTU.StationName = Console.ReadLine();
        Test_RTU.RTUmake = Console.ReadLine();
        Test_RTU.RTUtype = Console.ReadLine();
        Test_RTU.CommunicationType = Console.ReadLine();
        Test_RTU.DateInService = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Test_RTU
{
    public string EDiv { get; set; } //division that owns the asset
    public string StationName { get; set; } // name of station RTU is located
    public string RTUmake {get; set;}      
    public string RTUtype { get; set; }    
    public string CommunicationType { get; set; } 
    public string DateInService { get; set; }  


}
```

Comment: Well, `userInput` is an `Int32` and your `case` values are `char`s...

Comment: [Use your debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at `userInput`. Notice that `'1'` = 49 ≠ 1?

Comment: Shouldn't this still go to the default case? The chars would be cast to an int (with no matches) right?

Comment: @Lester, are the unconditional `Console.WriteLine` calls working for the initial prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Your switch cases should look like this:

```
case 1:
    ...
case 2:
    ...
case 3:
    ...
case 4:
    ...
```

not this:

```
case '1':
    ...
case '2':
    ...
case '3':
    ...
case '4':
    ...
```

`userInput` is an `int`, so the cases should be `int` literals as well. The literals that you are using (such as `'1'`) are `char` literals. There just so happens to be an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`, converting `'1'` to the integer `49`, `'2'` to the integer `50`, etc. Because of this implicit conversion, your code passes compilation, but doesn't work as expected.